# External url to get image src using php

Tags: php

Say i have this link

```
$url ="http://www.egyptian-planet.com/news-90.html";

//here get img or <meta property="og:image" from link
```

how can i get src img or get `<meta property="og:image"` from link (using PHP)?

Any help

Comment: Use `file_get_contents` or `cURL` to download the page, and an HTML DOM parser to parse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use cURL like this:-

```
function getHTML($url,$timeout)
{
       $ch = curl_init($url); // initialize curl with given url
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); // set  useragent
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // write the response to a variable
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // follow redirects if any
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout); // max. seconds to execute
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); // stop when it encounters an error
       return @curl_exec($ch);
}

$html=getHTML("http://www.egyptian-planet.com/news-90.html",10);

preg_match_all('/<img .*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', $html, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

**Another Solution:-**

You can also use [SimpleHtml](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) library to extract image like this:-

```
include_once("simple_html_dom.php");

$html=getHTML("http://www.egyptian-planet.com/news-90.html");

// Find all images on webpage
foreach($html->find("img") as $element)
echo $element->src . '<br>';
```